# PHP - understanding a basic class functionality

Tags: php, class

If I have the following PHP class example setup...

```
class foo {
  public $x = 2;

  public function getX() {
    return $this->x;
  }

  public function setX($val) {
    $this->x = $val - $this->x;
    return $this;
  } 
}

$X = (new foo)->setX(20)->getX();
```

How comes I need the ->getX(); part on the end of the object initiation process in order to get 18?  How come I simply can't hide the public getX() function and write...

```
$X = (new foo)->setX(20);
echo $X; // and show 18 without errors.
```

Instead it throws an error and says...

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class foo could not be converted to string in C:\...
```

Is not `$this->x`  refering to public `$x = 2`?  I guess I'm a little confused why we're depending on Public function `getX()`.  Thanks in advance for help understanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your returning an instance of the class `foo` when you do `return $this;`. If you want it to work as above then you need to return `$x` as shown below:

```
  public function setX($val) {
    $this->x = $val - $this->x;
    return $this->x;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`echo $X` tries to output the object. But your object doesn't have the [magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) `__toString()` so PHP has no way of knowing exactly **WHAT** to output when the object is used in a string context.

e.g. if you added this to your object definition:

```
public function __toString() {
   return $this->getX();
}
```

you'd "properly" get `18` when you do `echo $X`.

Comment: Thank you Marc B, I will add that to my knowledge now!